# Any unique identifier to identify Windows Embedded OS in Registry

Tags: operating-system, embedded, wmi

I'm developing a application that works on all windows terminals.The code works properly on all Windows OS except Windows Embedded Systems.So now I have to do some OS specific code changes.Is there any identifiers in Registry or WMI filters available that identifies the embedded systems?

Comment: Try searching for `"embedded"` at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/cimwin32prov/win32-operatingsystem

Comment: Thankyou @xmojmr . That was useful.